# Inserting batch of records into one table in SQL Server 2008 which contains composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am new to spring source and SQL Server, sorry for this question. I am trying to insert rows into a table (`IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES`). This table has a composite key which is connected to another parent table `EXT_INF_LOAD`.

So far, I was able to read from an input file and load all rows to `IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES` table
which has two keys: `EXT_INF_LOAD_ID` and `IN136_ID` with the following SQL statement:

INSERT statement:

```
 String sql = "insert into dbo.IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES (EXT_INF_LOAD_ID, IN136_ID, " + 
              "DEALER_NUM, " +
            "VSL_PURCHASE_DATE," +
                    "OWNERSHIP_ISSUED_DATE, " +
        "LAST_TRANSFER_DATE, " +
        "ODOMETER_CURRENT_DATE, " +
        "WORK_DATE, " +
                          "PURCHASE_PRICE, " +
        "VIN_HIN, " +
        "CURRENT_LICENSE, " +
        "REG_OWNER_NAME, " +
        "REG_OWNER_ADDRESS2, " +
        "REG_OWNER_ADDRESS3, " +
        "REG_OWNER_CITY_OR_STATE," +
        "LEGAL_OWNER_NAME," +
        "LEGAL_OWNER_ADDRESS2," +
        "LEGAL_OWNER_ADDRESS3," +
        "LEGAL_OWNER_CITY_OR_STATE," +
        "MAKE_BUILDER," +
        "YEAR_MODEL," +
        "VLF_CLASS," +
        "IRP_ACCOUNT_MX_NUM," +
        "IRP_ACCOUNT_NUM," +
        "IRP_ACCOUNT_USDOT_NUM," +
        "IRP_FLEET_MX_NUM," +
        "IRP_FLEET_NUM," +
        "IRP_FLEET_USDOT_NUM," +
        "IRP_VEH_MX_NUM," + 
        "IRP_VEH_USDOT_NUM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

JdbcTemplate jdbctempl = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbctempl.update(sql, new Object[] {id1, id2++, 
        rec.getDealerNum(),
              rec.getVslPurchaseDate(),
              rec.getOwnershipIssueDate(), 
              rec.getLastTransferDate(), 
        rec.getOdometerCurrentDate(),
        rec.getWorkDate(), 
        rec.getPurchasePrice(), 
        rec.getVinHin(),
        rec.getCurrentLicense(),
        rec.getRegOwnerName(),
        rec.getRegOwnerAddress2(),
        rec.getRegOwnerAddress3(),
        rec.getRegOwnerCityOrState(),
        rec.getLegalOwnerName(),
        rec.getLegalOwnerAddress2(),
        rec.getLegalOwnerAddress3(),
        rec.getLegalOwnerCityOrState(),
        rec.getMakeBuilder(),
        rec.getYearModel(),
        rec.getVlfClass(),
        rec.getIrpAccountMxNum(),
        rec.getIrpAccountNum(),
        rec.getIrpAccountUsdotNum(),
        rec.getIrpFleetMxNum(),
        rec.getIrpFleetNum(),
        rec.getIrpFleetUsdotNum(),
        rec.getIrpVehMxNum(),
        rec.getIrpVehUsdotNum()});
```

My problem is that in `IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES` (the child table), one of the columns of the composite key (`EXT_INF_LOAD_ID`) is connected to the `EXT_INF_LOAD` parent table.

So, I guess what I really need to do (but I don’t know how) is:

1. The information about `EXT_INF_ID` will be passed via parameter (I am calling it "counter" for now). I will have to read `EXT_INF` table, to see if I can find a match (`Counter = EXT_INF_ID`). So now that I found the row in `EXT_INF` table, I can get the value of `EXT_INF_NAME` column to   populate in `EXT_INF_LOAD` table (`EXT_INF_FILE_NAME` column).
2. Since I know the row exists in the `EXT_INF` table, I can insert a new row into the parent table (`EXT_INF_LOAD`) first, before starting to add new rows into the child table (`IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES`).
   The new row to be inserted into the parent table will have the following values:
       2.a `EXT_INF_ID = Counter`,
       2.b `EXT_INF_FILE_NAME = EXT_INF_NAME` (from the `EXT_INF` table)
       2.c `EXT_INF_LOAD_DATE` = todays-date
       2.d But what about the for `EXT_INF_FILE_NAME`?
3. That way, I will be able to keep adding other new input files into `IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES` table, as they arise. And as long as I use the same value `EXT_INF_LOAD_ID` for both : `EXT_INF_LOAD` (parent table)  and `IN136_DMV_USED_CAR_SALES` (child table), right?

But then I realized that (2.d) cannot also be passed via another `counter2` parameter for example, because the values of `EXT_INF_ID` and `EXT_INF_LOAD_ID` have to be unique, i.e., no duplicates are allowed...

I was hoping that  someone could help me find the correct way  to create all the required SQL   statements because I have been having so much problems / exception errors.(I am also new to SQL Server)

Thanks in advance for your interest in this matter. Sorry could not upload a picture of the tables, but here are the SQL statements for all 3 tables:

Table 1: **EXT_INF**

```
SELECT [EXT_INF_ID]
      ,[EXT_INF_NAME]
      ,[EXT_INF_DESC]
  FROM [boeafspdev1].[dbo].[EXT_INF]
 where EXT_INF_ID = counter
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT [EXT_INF_ID]
  ,[EXT_INF_LOAD_ID]
  ,[EXT_INF_FILE_NAME]
  ,[EXT_INF_LOAD_DATE]
  ,[EXT_INF_COMMENTS]
FROM [boeafspdev1].[dbo].[EXT_INF_LOAD]
where EXT_INF_ID = counter
```